# No property on type union object or array of objects

Tags: typescript

Currently my component contains an interface that has `value: ReactSelectOptions | ReactSelectOptions[];` and it's defined as

```
export interface ReactSelectOptions {
  value: string | number;
  label: string;
}
```

but if I try to access `value.label` or `value[0].label` I get an error saying

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"label"' can't be used to index type 'ReactSelectOptions | ReactSelectOptions[]'.
```

and

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'ReactSelectOptions | ReactSelectOptions[]'.
```

What's the issue here and how can I approach this?

Btw, I also have another property `isMulti: boolean` that's why I sometimes need my value to be array of objects if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that `value` could be `ReactSelectOptions` or an array `ReactSelectOptions[]`. TS doesn't know what the type is gonna be as this is gonna be decided at runtime, so it forces you to make compile time checks.

For your case checking if the var is an array should suffice. Something similar to this should get you going:

```
interface ReactSelectOptions {
  value: string | number;
  label: string;
}

function someF(maybeArr:ReactSelectOptions | ReactSelectOptions[]) {
 if (Array.isArray(maybeArr)) {
  maybeArr[0].label
 } else {
  maybeArr.label
 }
}
```